# Can one be banned from TfL services?

Tags: england-and-wales, trespass, transportation, private-property

Btp are often keen to advise that station staff are entitled at their own discretion to refuse members of the public carriage or entry to the stations like any privately owned business and it becomes then a civil matter between the parties.

But tfl is paid for by the public as an essential service with taxes.

Other private businesses are able to permanently ban one from admission to their places of business. Can tfl do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

- [Here is a tally of bans from a four-year period](https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/transparency/freedom-of-information/foi-request-detail?referenceId=FOI-1132-1920).
- [Here is one specific example](https://blackburnnews.com/london/london-news/2020/10/22/woman-banned-london-transit-buses-driver-assaulted/).

Comment: Okay but it seems that that was through police/court involvement. It seems thus that you can't be banned in quite the same way, with quite the same discretionary latitude of utterly arbitrary caprice or without grounds as from a private business.

Comment: "*X* has happened in the past" isn't really the same thing as "*X* is legal."

Comment: Yes and I think a better answer would explain through which legal provisions it could/world be done. However that it has happened numerous times does strongly suggest that there exists a legal mechanism for doing it.

Comment: With the “specific example”, yes, the police got involved, but I don’t see that as related to the ban. “If you hit our bus drivers you get banned from our buses”. “If you hit our bus drivers the police may arrest you for assault”.